# Ubuntu MATE 15.04 boots black screen blinking cursor after install?

Tags: grub2, mate, nomodeset, 15.04

I've edited GRUB with different nomodeset parameters but cannot boot past black screen with cursor?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean Ubuntu Mate 14.04?  There is a link to a list of suggestions to help in this situation [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: I wanted to give the alpha a spin as has one touch Compiz activation plus various themes, (Redmond etc...)

Comment: GRUB was not installed to correct HDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you booted from and used USB drive as a install medium, install process might end without errors but GRUB might not be installed correctly on the HDD.

I've experienced this odd behavior a dozen times from 12.04 onward.

Subsequent boot to Live environment and manually installing GRUB fixed this issue for me every time. Also, affected boxes do get correct GRUB if booted and installed from DVD.

In my experience occurrence is rare and hardware specific so I never had a chance/time to get to the bottom of the problem.